# 画像ファイルが読み込めず、shapeを取得することができない。

Tags: python, python3, opencv

Pythonで画像認識のための学習データを準備するために、OpenCVを使って以下の各フォルダの中にある画像をすべて、短いほうの辺に合わせて正方形にクリッピングし保存するプログラムを書いています。

```
data/arisu
　　/aya
　　/karen
　　/shino
　　/youko
```

しかし、これを実行すると、ファイルを探せないのかエラーが出てしまいます。

```
　height, width = img.shape[:2]
AttribteError: 'NoneType' object has no attribte 'shape'
```

ファイル・フォルダを取得したfor文を書いたことがなかったため未熟な点もありますが、どなたかわかる方がいたら教えてください。

```
import os
import cv2
dirs = ['arisu', 'aya', 'karen', 'shino', 'youko']
for i in range(len(dirs)):
    d = dirs[i]
    files = os.listdir("../data/" + d)
    for j in range(len(files)):
        f = files[j]
        img = cv2.imread("../data/" + d + "/" + f)
        height, width = img.shape[:2]
        if(height > width):             #縦長だった場合
            clp = img[0:width, 0:width] #左上からwidthの長さの正方形にクリップ

        if(height < width):                 #横長だった場合
            offset = ((width//2)-(height//2))   #左側の余白部分をoffset
            clp = img[0:height, offset:offset+height]   #offsetの位置からheightの長さの正方形にクリップ
            cv2.imwrite("../data/" + d + "/" + f, clp)
```

Comment: cv2.imreadの前に、「"../data/" + d + "/" + f」　の値を表示してみてください。適切なファイルのパスになっていますか？

Comment: pythonの対話モードで一行ずつ確認したところ、正常に画像を読み込むことができている、またimshowなどでも表示できることを確認しました。

Comment: cv2.imreadした後、「if img != None:」を挟み、Noneだったときはprint("失敗")だけしてfor文の頭に戻る、という仕様変更をしたところ、正しく動きました。

追記：質問のソースコード(クリッピングと除算演算子)に誤りがあったので修正をしました。

Answer (score 1):

cv2.imreadした後、`if img != None:`を挟み、Noneだったときはprint("失敗")だけしてfor文の頭に戻る、という仕様変更をしたところ、正しく動きました。

---

<sup>この投稿は @3614013 s さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38226/#comment38476_38226)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>